# Open-Source Java XML-RPC client

Tags: library, java, web-services

I am looking for an open source XML-RPC client for my application to use to talk to XML-RPC servers.

The application currently uses [Apache XML-RPC 3.1.3](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/changes-report.html), however this has several CVEs recorded against it, and does not appear to be in active development (it is listed as an archived project on [this page](https://ws.apache.org/)).

The library needs to support TLS with a customisable SSL context.

Comment: XML RPC is AFAIK an outdated technology, usually SOAP is used instead. Are you sure you can't use SOAP?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware XML-RPC was so outdated. I'm not able to influence the interface exposed by the servers, unfortunately.

Comment: How complex is the interface? If it is rather simple and don't have many methods you can just generate the XML DOM for a request yourself.

Comment: It's not very complex, so I suppose that is an option. I was hoping not to have to roll my own though, especially as organisations like Apache haven't managed to make theirs totally secure.

Comment: Vulnerabilities usually are created by configuration options and variants. If you don't support the and instead just parse the dom and extract information from it what should go wrong? Also the server side is way more fragile as the client side.

Comment: You may be better off with a widely used library with known CVEs that you can avoid exposing, rather than a less used library which has not had the same scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

So the only open sorce alternative to apache one seems to be [aXMLRPC](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/61623)

Comment: @Chenmunka Shuld I just copy the readmee?